# Why there should be at least one vector of a set in the span of the rest, for the set to be Linearly Dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I think the title seems a bit too complex. However, it is all about this theorem:

> A set $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is Linearly Dependent if and only if there is at least one vector $v_k \in \{v_1,...,v_m\}$ which is in the span of $\{v_1,...,v_{k-1},v_{k+1},...,v_m\}$.

I do understand the concept when I see a couple of examples but the actual theorem is quite hard to digest.
Can someone please help me get a better idea of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ are linearly dependent, then there exists some $c_1,\ldots, c_n$ which are not all zero such that
$$c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0.$$
Suppose it's $c_j$ which is nonzero. Then
$$c_jv_j=-(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_{j-1}v_{j-1}+c_{j+1}v_{j+1}+\cdots+c_nv_n)$$
implies
$$v_j=-\frac{1}{c_j}(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_{j-1}v_{j-1}+c_{j+1}v_{j+1}+\cdots+c_nv_n).$$

Comment: Thank you. Got it!